# iOS: XCode 4.4.1: xcodebuild error - Unable to read diagnostics from file

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcodebuild

So I would like to use xcodebuild in Terminal to create a build from a test application (called RunTeszt1). The app is an iOS single view application with nothing in it, just created and closed.

**When I this from the Terminal, the build fails.**

```
xcodebuild -target "RunTeszt1" -sdk "$iphoneos5" -configuration Debug
```

**The error is:**

`Unable to read diagnostics from file "/var/folders/6s/cjw35hhs5lb6wpnx9m8lr2km0000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/RunTeszt1-Prefix-eqntxoxxhhlzvieuipqbxfumbpxb/RunTeszt1-Prefix.pch.dia" (Invalid File): Bad header in diagnostics file`

```
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

When I run the app from XCode (4.4.1), the build completes and everything is ok. However, If I run the Console app and inspect the results after hitting build button in XCode, I see the same error message in the console. Nevertheless the build succeeds and opens the simulator.

Is this really a bug in xcodebuild which should be sent to apple? If it is I imagine a bunch of people already sent it.

**How can I either make the error go away, or stop it from cancelling the building process, so circumvent it like XCode does?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was **code signing**. Even though I put `Don't code sign` in the build settings, it still hanged up on it. Also it seems "`-sdk xxx`" was also at fault (no matter what sdk I specified).
Running this command resulted in a successful build:

```
xcodebuild clean build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO -target RunTeszt2
```