# iOS: XCode 4.5: xcodebuild error - fatal error: 'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, command-line, xcodebuild

So I would like to use xcodebuild in Terminal to create a build from a test application (called RunTeszt2). The app is an iOS single view application with nothing in it, just created and closed.

**When I try this from the Terminal, the build fails.**

```
xcodebuild -target "RunTeszt2" -sdk "$iphoneos5" -configuration Debug
```

**The error is:**

`/Users/toodygarik/Desktop/RunTeszt2/RunTeszt2/RunTeszt2-Prefix.pch:12:13: fatal error: 'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`

```
The following build commands failed:
ProcessPCH /var/folders/6s/cjw35hhs5lb6wpnx9m8lr2km0000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501
/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/RunTeszt2-Prefix-bxwegbsdjylasccydwchfkbjadur/
RunTeszt2-Prefix.pch.pth RunTeszt2/RunTeszt2-Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c
com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

When I run the app from XCode (4.5), the build completes and everything is ok. I checked the console.app log when running the app from XCode and it does not display the error message above.

What is causing this issue?

EDIT: **Based on `H2CO3`'s comment, I edited the Other C Flags entry of the project's Build Settings, like this:**

```
-isysroot $SDKROOT
```

... and now that particular issue is solved. I'm back to my other xcodebuild related issue: [iOS: XCode 4.4.1: xcodebuild error - Unable to read diagnostics from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514629/ios-xcode-4-4-1-xcodebuild-error-unable-to-read-diagnostics-from-file)

Thanks, `H2CO3`!

Comment: How can I set it, and what should it be set to?

Comment: Add "-isysroot <SYSROOT>" to the compiler and linker flags, where SYSROOT should be the path of the iPhoneOSXXX.sdk directory (XXX is the version number).

Comment: How can I find the directory where the sdk is? Should I put the path in "Other linker flags" in the build settings? Or some place else?

Comment: Yes, other linker/compiler flags is fine, and it's usually somewhere in /Developer/Platforms or in /Applications/Xcode.app.

Comment: I found the sdk and tried to create the flag. Please see the edit I made to the original question.

Comment: I made this an answer, please upvote/accept if it helped. Also, I found [this](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?pid=1105569) for you - this guy had a similar issue to yours. (Es koszi megegyszer, remelem, sikerul megoldani! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the development sysroot of the particular OS you're targetting, or else the compiler and linker cannot find the headers and libraries. Add `-isysroot <SYSROOT>` to the compiler and linker flags, where `SYSROOT` should be the full path of the `iPhoneOSXXX.sdk` directory (XXX is the version number of iOS).